# what happens to a function bound to last-child when the last child changes?

Tags: jquery-selectors, jquery

I use the following selector and function:

```
$("form[name='qc']:last-child").live("focus", newTextLine);
```

when the `:last-child` will change, will the `.live` still be listening to the old `:last-child`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live) (and [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate)) tests the selector when the event happens.  If the element is not the last child when it is clicked, the handler won't be executed.

[`bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind) (and other methods that use it, such as [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click)), by contrast, tests the selector at the time of the binding, not of the event.

Comment: thanx, BTW I tried to switch to `delegate` and it doesn't works `$("form#qc").delegate("input:last", "focus", newTextLine);` can you tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: @Ilya `:last` Checks whether the element is the last one in the selection. This is *always* true with a single-element selection (as used in `delegate`). I think you mean `:last-child`.